# The menu at the bootstrap do not want to grow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page template for bootstrap: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/upl/grafika/
Site comes okey. As soon as it reduces the maximum (width) that appears in the top right corner of the rectangle.
After clicking on the menu should be developed rather than developing .... Maybe anyone know how to fix it?

Please help me,

Northwest

Comment: you need to try an explain yourself better, cause I didn't really understand what is the problem

Comment: The relevant code should be included in the question, as the link is likely to break at some point. So please produce a minimal example of the issue and include the relevant code in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.